# Cannot utilise multiprocessing shared memory to save output from multiprocessing function

Tags: python, global-variables, python-multiprocessing, shared-memory

I am writing a program to extract information from the web and save it in a Python list. I use a multiprocessing method to extract the information and is experiencing problems saving the output list for further processing. This is my code:

```
import multiprocessing

def web_scrape1():
    #some codes to scrape the web output 3 lists
    global sub_list1a, sub_list2a, sub_list3a
    sub_list1a.append(scrape1)
    sub_list2a.append(scrape2)
    sub_list3a.append(scrape3)

def web_scrape2():
    #some codes to scrape the web output 3 lists
    global sub_list1b, sub_list2b, sub_list3b
    sub_list1b.append(scrape1)
    sub_list2b.append(scrape2)
    sub_list3b.append(scrape3)

def master_scraper():
    ws1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=web_scrape1)
    ws2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=web_scrape2)

    ws1.start()
    ws2.start()
    ws1.join()
    ws2.join()

    global master_list1, master_list2, master_list3

    master_list1 = sub_list1a + sub_list1b
    master_list2 = sub_list2a + sub_list2b
    master_list3 = sub_list3a + sub_list3b

def postprocessing():
    #some codes to process the lists
    print(master_list1) # Output []
    print(master_list2) # Output []
    print(master_list3) # Output []

def main():
  master_scraper()
  postprocessing()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  multiprocessing.freeze_support()
  main()
```

the output for the above code is simply:

```
[]
[]
[]
```

I tried to assign all the list to a shared memory using something like this `multiprocessing.Array('b', sub_list1a)` inside the `web_scape1()`, `master_scraper()` and `main()` function but the list still comes back as `[]`.

Hope to get some help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `multiprocessing`, you can't use global variables, because processes hold their own area of memory, a change inside each process is independent. The simplest way of accomplishing what you are trying is to use a `Manager` to communicate between processes. You can create `output_container` and pass it to each function so they can access it and modify it. For example:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp


def web_scrape1(output_container: list):
    sample_text = 'value from web_scrape1'
    output_container.append(sample_text)


def web_scrape2(output_container: list):
    sample_text = 'value from web_scrape2'
    output_container.append(sample_text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    output_container = mp.Manager().list()

    worker1 = mp.Process(target=web_scrape1, args=(output_container,))
    worker2 = mp.Process(target=web_scrape2, args=(output_container,))

    worker1.start()
    worker2.start()

    worker1.join()
    worker2.join()

    print(output_container)
    >>> ['value from web_scrape1', 'value from web_scrape2']
```

You can find more information in [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Marcos.

Does the line `output_container = mp.Manager().list()` needs to be inside `if __name__ == "__main__"` ? Can I key that into another function and run the function  inside main program execution?

Comment: @TengBangWei the line `if __name__ == "__main__"` means if you are running this script directly then execute the code below. You can put your container wherever you want as long as you pass it as an argument function of `mp.Process`, so it has to be in the same scope.

Comment: Thank you @Marcos.